Eliminación de cadenas en una lista de tokens
Estoy haciendo unas líneas de código que pretenden eliminar las cadenas "pfizer" y "pfizergate" de una lista de tokens, las líneas son las siguientes:
remove_tokens <- function(tokens, remove_tokens) {
  pattern <- paste0("^", remove_tokens, "$")  # Improved pattern
  tokens[!grepl(pattern, tokens)]
}

remove_tokens <- c("pfizer", "pfizergate")

filtered_tokens <- remove_tokens(tokens2, remove_tokens)

Y me da el siguiente error:
 Error in remove_tokens(tokens2, remove_tokens) : 
  could not find function "remove_tokens"

Le he preguntado a la IA de google y me vuelve a dar el mismo código. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano y decirme donde falla el código?

Estas nombrando la variable remove_token igual que la función, lógicamente la variable sobreescribe a la función, remove-tokens y no existe como función

Muchas gracias, pero me sigue sin quitar la cadena pfizergate, no entiendo el motivo

Adicional al comentario de Patricio, podrias valorar que una opción podría ser que te bases en %in% para validar la existencia de elementos de un vector en otro y así, luego filtrar:
remove_tokens_2 <- function(tokens, remove_tokens){
  out <- tokens[!tokens %in% remove_tokens]
  return(out)
}

Ejemplo:
target <- c("pfizer", "pfizergate")
tokens <- c("aa", "bb", "pfizer", "cc", "pfizergate", "zz", "123")

# aplicación de función
remove_tokens_2(tokens, remove_tokens = target)
[1] "aa"  "bb"  "cc"  "zz"  "123"

Otra opción es usar setdiff
remove_tokens_3 <- function(tokens, remove_tokens = target){
  out <- setdiff(tokens, remove_tokens)
  return(out)
}

remove_tokens_3(tokens, tokens_to_be_removed)
[1] "aa"  "bb"  "cc"  "zz"  "123"


Muchas gracias, he probado con los dos códigos y sigue sin eliminar del todo esas cadenas, la lista de tokens de donde tienen que desaparecer esas dos cadenas, "pfizer" y "pfizergate", se llama tokens2 y ese nombre he puesto donde usted  pone tokens, pero sigue sin funcionar, desconozco el motivo

@jonas en tokens debe ir el vector donde están todas las cadenas y en remove_tokens debes poner el vector de cadenas a ser eliminandas, en este caso pfizer y pfizergate las cuales he guardado bajo el nombre de target en la reciente versión editada de mi respuesta.
